# How to fix different drawable in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner android developer
I want to resolve this problem,but i cant.
the images size are 84*91 and show properly in Nexus 6 device on XML preview in android studio.
[image]

but in nexus 5 and etc. not working properly

[image]

also the image quality change.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:background="@drawable/home_btn_selector"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/_btn1"
            android:text="سرویس های پایان نیافته"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"></View>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:background="@drawable/home_btn_selector"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/_btn2"

            android:text="پیشنهاد های پاسخ داده نشده"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
       >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:background="@drawable/home_btn_selector"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/_btn3"
            android:text="وضعیت مالی"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:background="@drawable/home_btn_selector"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/_btn4"
            android:text="سرویس های شروع نشده"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post whole xml code..

Comment: @DivyeshPatel I do it

Comment: where is your imageview?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel i dont using image view...i use a button and a drawable in it

Comment: it is wrong practice, but if you want then it is ok.

Comment: and try to use relative layout, without weight

Comment: @DivyeshPatel ok.
that is not relation to mdpi,hdpi and etc. drawable ?
how to i fix changing image quality?

Comment: You may read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information on how to fix your problem

Comment: @VygintasB i read this link but i confuse

Comment: @Mehrdad_75 You may have read it,  but you need not only to read, but understand too. My advice for you to tkae 2-3 hours and read it all till you understand. This concept is very crucial for android developing and if you learn this as soon as posible, it will ease your learning a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement this way to solve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_button"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:src="@drawable/iv_user_ph" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Test" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_button"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:src="@drawable/iv_user_ph" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Test" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_button"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:src="@drawable/iv_user_ph" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Test" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_button"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:src="@drawable/iv_user_ph" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Test" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Add background drawble of button to linearlayout background and Image of drawableTop to ImageView src.

Comment: Yeees
thats work properly
but in nexus 4 or nexus 5 the image quality is bad
how i resolve it?

Comment: @Mehrdad_75    check with other Large size Image, because of fixed size image quality is bad.

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/accent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4.75">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4.75">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4.75"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_fb"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/bg_actionbar"
                    android:text="سرویس های پایان نیافته"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView6" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:background="@color/accent_bright"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_fb"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/bg_actionbar"

            android:text="پیشنهاد های پاسخ داده نشده"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_fb"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/bg_actionbar"
            android:text="وضعیت مالی"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.75"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_fb"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/bg_actionbar"
            android:text="سرویس های شروع نشده"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
```